# SysV start a script using local nvm

Tags: init-script, sysvinit

I have node installed in the users home directory. 
I have a program I want started on a headless machine to run a program using that users npm install.

`sudo -u pi npm -v` says npm not found.
`su pi -c 'npm -v'` says npm not found.

What is the proper way to do this in a SysV script?